# could not find any instance of Visual Studio

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Goal:** I intend to install ROS2 Dashing on Windows.  I am building from source following the instructions in https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing/Windows-Development-Setup/.

**Issue**: When running `colcon build --merge-install` from the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt each package starts to be built.  However, it fails on the same error:

```
--- stderr: <package>
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  Generator

    Visual Studio 16 2019

  could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
```

I have added an `AMENT_IGNORE` file to each package to see if the problem is with an individual package, but the error is occuring in every package.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334454/could-not-find-any-instance-of-visual-studio./) by [Tav_PG](https://answers.ros.org/users/43825/tav_pg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-10-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cangyin](https://answers.ros.org/users/44655/cangyin/) on 2019-12-29**:
I am also struggling on similar problem,  hope this will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668676/cmake-visual-studio-15-2017-could-not-find-any-instance-of-visual-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Apology:** Firstly I would like to apologise, I'm under some pressure to get ROS2 installed on Windows, and I am posting some issues that I resolve soon after posting them! (sorry)  However, more information for the community is better, just in case someone else runs into the same issue.

**Appreciation:** Thank you cangyin for your input.  You found the solution.

**Cause:** When following the https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing/Windows-Install-Binary/ instructions at the "Install Visual Studio" section it states,

> Make sure that no C++ CMake tools are
> installed by unselecting them in the
> list of components to be installed.

I was slightly confused that the accompanying screenshot in the instructions shows 'Visual C++ tools for CMake' checked.  So at this point I thought it would be 'safer' :-) to uncheck all the optional components.  This was my downfall.

**Solution:**

[1] Open Visual Studio

[2] On the menu go to Tools > Get Tools and Features

[3] Make sure the "Desktop development with C++" tab is enabled (checked) under the "Workloads" section

[4] In the right side panel

**Thanks again to cangyin**

---

Originally posted by [Tav_PG](https://answers.ros.org/users/43825/tav_pg/) with karma: 28 on 2020-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1